# Query top 10 records with maximum number of child records

Tags: soql

How to query a parent record which has maximum number of child records associated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve in this simple way:-

1. Create a Rollup Summary field on parent Object
2. Write a query like:

> ```
>  [SELECT id, desired_field__c    FROM Parent_Object__c    ORDER BY
>  Rollup_Summary_Field__c DESC   LIMIT 10];
> ```

It will return top 10 parent records having child records count in Descending Order.

> **Note:** This will work if objects have master-detail relationship.